# List top 3 most recent pdfs from Silverstripe Files tab

Tags: php, pdf, silverstripe

I'm pretty new to Silverstripe, although, I have some decent PHP experience.

Right now, I am working on getting the PDF files I uploaded in the Silverstripe CMS under the Files tab.

I have them stored in a folder called "Newsletters," and I want to get the title for each (so I can make a downloadable hyperlink with it) and the date uploaded. So far, I have found tutorials on how to upload files and I found this bit of code for getting an image out of the upload directory:

```
 function getFrontPageImages() {
      $folder = DataObject::get_one("Folder", "Filename = 'assets/myfrontpageimages'");
      return $folder ? DataObject::get("Image", "ParentID = '{$folder->ID}'") : false;
    }
```

But that's not exactly what I want, considering I want to get 3 PDFs. Is there a good example on how to do this?

I am guessing it's something similar to `$[something].Title` and `$[something].LastEdited` (or something similar)?

Comment: What Silverstripe version are you using? The code you pasted seems a bit outdated (was from 2.4 times), if you're using 3.1 you have to do something like File::get()->filter() to get the last files. See http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/#filtering-results and http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/

Comment: I'm using Silverstripe 3.1. The example I posted above was from an online forum, and I wasn't sure if it was still usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP (Page_Controller or sub-class, generally):

```
<?php
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    public function FeaturedPDFs() {
        $folder = Folder::get()->filter('Filename', 'assets/featured-pdfs')->first();
        // Could do $folder->Children()->sort('Filename', 'ASC') to sort by filename, here I'm going to show the 3 most recently edited files
        return $folder
            ->Children()
            ->sort('LastEdited', 'DESC')
            ->limit(3);
    }
}
?>
```

In your template (e.g. in this case, Page.ss):

```
<% if $FeaturedPDFs %>
    <ul>
        <% loop $FeaturedPDFs %>
            <%-- Here, you're in the scope of a `File` object --%>
            <li>$Title.XML (last edited on $LastEdited.Format('Y-m-d') at $LastEdited.Time)</li>
        <% end_loop %>
    <ul>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but when I try to load the page, it's entirely blank. Removing the code above allows it to work again. I don't see any errors in Chrome's dev tools but something must be wrong. It seems like this should work, though. I only changed the assets/featured-pdfs to assets/Newsletters.

Comment: Scratch that--I finally managed to get it working. There were some issues with the date-time setup on my system.